# Retrieve rows which satisfy at least four of given seven conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a table called as 'Alphabets' with columns named from 'A to G'.

```
Table Name: Alphabets

Column Names: A | B | C | D | E | F | G
```

Now, I need a SQL query to retrieve all rows from the table which satisfy at least four criteria from the following list:

```
A = 1   
B = 2  
C = 3  
D = 4  
E = 5  
F = 6
G = 7
```

I am using Oracle 10g database.

Comment: Could you edit your post and say on what DB are you working? the query can be slightly different in base at this information.

Comment: @ppeterka: I am not able to get any idea of doing this.

Comment: @Bagatin: Added. I am using oracle 10g.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Alphabets where
CASE WHEN A=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN B=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN C=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN D=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN E=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN F=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN G=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 4
```

But something about this table and query seem suspect - It feels like it should really be a table of two columns, `Letter` and `Value` say.

Answer (score 5):

One ugly solution I could think of (I'm sure there must be better solutions, but this one should work, though I'm not conviced it is optimal in any sense...)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Alphabets
WHERE
CASE WHEN A=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN B=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN C=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN D=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN E=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN F=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN G=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END BETWEEN 4 AND 7
```

This has problems:

- doesn't scale well - new constraint - new line in query...
- performance wise it is not optimal
- also just plain horribly ugly